# Android Peer to Peer Video transfer using socket.io

Tags: android, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to implement peer to peer video transfer. So what i did

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(UPLOAD_FILE_PATH));
byte[] fileArray = new byte[4095];
int byteSend;
while((byteSend = input.read(fileArray)) != -1) {
            //System.out.println(String.valueOf(fileArray));
            StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
            content.append(new String(fileArray));
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("id",i++);
            obj.put("FileArrray",content);
            obj.put("byteSend",byteSend);
            mSocket.emit("mp4", obj);
            byteSendTracker = byteSendTracker+byteSend;
            System.out.println("send"+Arrays.toString(fileArray));
           // output.write(fileArray,0,byteSend);
            Thread.sleep(10);
           }
   output.flush(); 
   input.close();
```

So what i did is send This FileArrray as String buffer to node socket.io 
and from socket.io to another connected client

```
socket.on("mp4",function(data){
   console.log(data.id);
    socket.broadcast.emit("getFile",data);
});
```

then on receivers side i simply Write a file as below:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(args[0]));
output.write(obj.getString("FileArrray").getBytes(),0,Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("byteSend")));
```

i tried sending 240kb mp4 video when it get uploaded file is corrupted. Can any one point me to right direction to do it.